# Remove or hide "wc_add_notice" messages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, notice

I am using this to remove the "Cart is updated" message in WooCommerce:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_message', '__return_false');
```

But the "Shipping costs updated" message is still displayed. How can I remove this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, in [shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ab4a46e32e338cbf33094ab26144744a021a21a9/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-cart.php) we find:

```php
wc_add_notice( __( 'Shipping costs updated.', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
```

Which in turn calls the `wc_add_notice()` function:

```php
...
// Backward compatibility.
if ( 'success' === $notice_type ) {
    $message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_message', $message );
}

$message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_' . $notice_type, $message );
...
```

(This code was partly copied from: [includes/wc-notice-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-notice-functions.php))

---

So instead of using the `woocommerce_add_message` filter hook you can use the `woocommerce_add_"$notice_type"` filter hook.

`$notice_type` = the name of the notice type - **either error, success (default) or notice.**

In your case, `$notice_type`
corresponds with **notice**. So then just compare the message, if this is sufficient, we return false:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add( $message ) {
    // Equal to (Must be exactly the same).
    // If the message is displayed in another language, adjust where necessary!
    if ( $message == 'Shipping costs updated.' ) {
        return false;
    }   
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'filter_woocommerce_add', 10, 1 );
// OR - Use the desired filter, depending on the name of the notice type (default = success)
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'filter_woocommerce_add', 10, 1 );
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'filter_woocommerce_add', 10, 1 );
```